# check the amount of free RAM using rust

Tags: python, rust, ram

In python, I could get some RAM parameters using the psutil module:

```
import psutil
psutil.virtual_memory()
```

This is how the output looks like:

```
>>> psutil.virtual_memory()
vmem(total=8589934592L, available=4073336832L,
percent=52.6, used=5022085120L, free=3560255488L,
active=2817949696L, inactive=513081344L, wired=1691054080L)
```

Is there a way to do something like this using rust?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize [sysinfo crate](https://docs.rs/sysinfo/latest/sysinfo/index.html)

official e.g.

```rust
use sysinfo::{NetworkExt, NetworksExt, ProcessExt, System, SystemExt};

// Please note that we use "new_all" to ensure that all list of
// components, network interfaces, disks and users are already
// filled!
let mut sys = System::new_all();

// First we update all information of our `System` struct.
sys.refresh_all();

// We display all disks' information:
println!("=> disks:");
for disk in sys.disks() {
    println!("{:?}", disk);
}

// Network interfaces name, data received and data transmitted:
println!("=> networks:");
for (interface_name, data) in sys.networks() {
    println!("{}: {}/{} B", interface_name, data.received(), data.transmitted());
}

// Components temperature:
println!("=> components:");
for component in sys.components() {
    println!("{:?}", component);
}

println!("=> system:");
// RAM and swap information:
println!("total memory: {} bytes", sys.total_memory());
println!("used memory : {} bytes", sys.used_memory());
println!("total swap  : {} bytes", sys.total_swap());
println!("used swap   : {} bytes", sys.used_swap());

// Display system information:
println!("System name:             {:?}", sys.name());
println!("System kernel version:   {:?}", sys.kernel_version());
println!("System OS version:       {:?}", sys.os_version());
println!("System host name:        {:?}", sys.host_name());

// Number of CPUs:
println!("NB CPUs: {}", sys.cpus().len());

// Display processes ID, name na disk usage:
for (pid, process) in sys.processes() {
    println!("[{}] {} {:?}", pid, process.name(), process.disk_usage());
}
```